# Pack a uncased 2.5" HDD with a Pi 2 in one case

Tags: pi-2, hard-drive, case

I want to pack a Raspberry Pi 2 and a uncased 2.5" HDD in one case. The HDD is connected with a SATA-to-USB-cable. It doesn't matter for me if that cable is outside of the case.

I can not find something like that. Does anyone know a solution for that?

btw: It would be nice if I could add this case to the VESA place, too.

Comment: What does "nacked" mean?  I don't understand the reference to either "nacked" or "poor" in this usage.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: It means no case. "bulked"?

Comment: Do you mean "naked"?

Comment: @buhtz In English probably uncased to mean an item without a case.

Comment: I've seen USB-to-IDE/SATA Adapters, indeed I have one - but the unit only supplies Power to the SATA drive and uses a E-SATA signal (that has probably been converted improperly by a normal SATA-to-E-SATA adapter plate on an expansion slot on a PC).  That sort of thing is not going to work on the (Raspberry) Pi as that has no SATA (the Banana Pi does but those are *not a fit topic of conversation here*!).  Whether a true USB-to-SATA interface/adapter is available I do not know.  How are you going to power the "bare" (not "naked"!) drive?

Comment: The Pi2 should have enough power over its USB itself. I just use the USB-cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options for a vesa mounted raspberry pi case, among them is this one.

[http://www.amazon.com/VESA-Mount-Case-Raspberry-Pi/dp/B00P9VK71W](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00P9VK71W)

However I haven't heard of any cases for the raspberry pi 2 that also hold an hdd and is vesa mountable.

https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/plusberry-pi-media-box-running-on-raspberry-pi#/

This one from several years ago fits your requirements, but is for the original pi